# Validate JSON response key label is present and value is not null in java

Tags: java, rest-assured

We have API which gives response array with label and values
Below is structure

```
"Name":"XYZ"
 "Resultid": [
        {
            "subject": "English",            
            "Marks": "79"
        },
        {
           "subject": "English",            
            "Marks": "79"

        }
```

We need to check that Subject and Marks will always have value which is not null .
Below is the code

```
List<Map<String, String>> allResultid = response.jsonPath().getList("Resultid");
        for (Map<String, String> map : allResultid) {
            
                
                assertEquals(map.get("subject"), not(blankOrNullString()));             
                assertEquals(map.get("Marks"), not(blankOrNullString()));
  }
```

getting error expected and actual doesnot match. Please help to check value will be always present.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please take the line "getting error expected..." outside of code highlighting area. Also please edit the example code via indentation to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `isNull`

```
if(!allResultid.isNull("subject")) {
    //Throw Error
}
```

Or you can try

```
if( allResultid.get("subject").equals(null) ){
        //Throw Error
}
```

Comment: There is no isNull in java , can be use this options assertEquals(map.get("subject"), not(blankOrNullString())); but still not working.   if(!allResultid.isEmpty)  which is not working

Comment: You need to add the proper dependencies of `json.simple` to use `isNull()`

Answer (score 0):

To null check in java, you can use **!= null**. So, check null and then perform next task. You can also check null for **Resultid** similar way.

```
List<Map<String, String>> allResultid = response.jsonPath().getList("Resultid");
for (Map<String, String> map : allResultid) {
            
   if( map.get("subject") != null){
      // do something
   }  
   ...
   if( map.get("Marks") != null){
      // do something
   }
             
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We have added just line to check null by using assert

```
assertNotNull(map.get("subject"));
```